# fping output vs. nmap -sn output behind two firewalls

Tags: linux, nmap

I've tried to scan a network, behind two firewalls, for online hosts only. With fping I did:

`fping -a -q -g 192.168.222.0/24`

and I got this output

```
@>~]$ > fping -a -q -g 192.168.222.0/24
192.168.222.1
192.168.222.23
192.168.222.53
192.168.222.86
```

when I did this with nmap I got this output (all host are online, which is not true):

```
@>~]$ > nmap -n -sn 192.168.222.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-07 19:10 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.0
Host is up (0.016s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.1
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.2
Host is up (0.0040s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.3
Host is up (0.0053s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.4
Host is up (0.0053s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.5
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.6
Host is up (0.0040s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.7
Host is up (0.0074s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.8
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.9
Host is up (0.0039s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.10
Host is up (0.0039s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.11
Host is up (0.015s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.1
Host is up (0.017s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.1
Host is up (0.0063s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.222.14
Host is up (0.0070s latency).
(...)
```

How I can get the nmap output like fping and without sudo?

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Comment: Admittedly, I don't know how to make `nmap` generate the same output as `fping`, but you seem to be surprised that `nmap` discovers more hosts. `fping` only uses ICMP echo requests, often named "pings". Read the paragraph on the [nmap -sn](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) option to see how `nmap` discovers hosts. Spoiler: It does more than echo requests. You could also run `tcpdump` to find out which precise test tells `nmap` that a host is up.

Answer (score 0):

I am the owner of those tested network range, and I know which host exist and which not and nmap with -sn parameter displays non existing hosts as online which is wrong! I know what nmap can do and can not. Check my progs at github: https://github.com/MrEnergy64/IPventur-Pro-1.5
At the moment I use fping in my progs to identify real existing hosts after firewall clusters or when someone has no sudo rights (some nmap commands can check hosts details often with sudo only where fping don't need sudo for). Actual I am on an IPventur project with python3 and I would like to prevent to use the cli fping command and would like to use python-nmap only, but without of a solution that nmap scan issue behind firewall infrastructures and still need to use fping. Until someone has a positive feedback and solution advise.